# How do I hand trace a Linked List X through the following operations?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, stack

I am trying to answer this question below and I am stuck.

Hand trace a Linked List X through the following operations:

```
X.add("Fast"); 
X.add("Boy"); 
X.add("Doctor"); 
X.add("Event"); 
X.add("City"); 
X.addLast("Zoo"); 
X.addFirst("Apple"); 
X.add (1, "Array");
X.remove("Fast");
X.remove (2);
X.removeFirst ();
X.removeLast ();
```

This is how I am handtracing it and I am trying to understand if/where I am doing wrong because I saw confusing answers elsewhere:

Fast

Boy Fast

DoctorBoyFast

Event DoctorBoyFast

City Event DoctorBoyFast

Zoo City Event DoctorBoyFast

Zoo City Event DoctorBoyFastApple

Zoo City Event DoctorBoyFastArrayApple

Zoo City Event DoctorBoyArrayApple

Zoo City Event DoctorArrayApple

Zoo City Event DoctorArray

City Event DoctorArray

Answer (score 1):

After performing the operation you will get below list:

Your LinkedList starts from the head. Now for first, you have to insert from the head and otherwise into last.

Fast

Boy->Fast

Doctor->Boy->Fast

Event->Doctor->Boy->Fast

City->Event->Doctor->Boy->Fast

City->Event->Doctor->Boy->Fast->Zoo // wrong Zoo->City->Event->Doctor->Boy->Fast

Apple->City->Event->Doctor->Boy->Fast->Zoo // wrong Zoo->City->Event-> Doctor->Boy->Fast->Apple

Apple->Array->City->Event->Doctor->Boy->Fast->Zoo // wrong because linked list should be started from apple but it not purely true because there is no indexing in LinkedList it should be on you.

Similarly, you can perform the other operation.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain? I thought it would be City-->Event-->Doctor--->Array. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you can check the updated answer and If you understand the explanation, please mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
X.add("Fast"); 
X.add("Boy"); 
X.add("Doctor"); 
X.add("Event"); 
X.add("City"); 
City->Event->Doctor->Boy->Fast
tail    ----- head
top   ---- bottom
top........0

X.addLast("Zoo"); 
X.addFirst("Apple");
Zoo->City->Event->Doctor->Boy->Fast->Apple

X.add (1, "Array");
Zoo->City->Event->Doctor->Boy->Fast->Array->Apple

X.remove("Fast");
Zoo->City->Event->Doctor->Boy->Array->Apple

X.remove (2);
Zoo->City->Event->Doctor->Array->Apple

X.removeFirst ();
Zoo->City->Event->Doctor->Array

X.removeLast ();
City->Event->Doctor->Array

Answer depends on , what each operation means,
Here is how I perceived them:
add("A") -> will append "A" as head to the linked list.
addFirst("A") -> will add "A" as head to the linked list i.e. first element.
addLast("A") -> will append "A" as tail to the linked list.
add (i, "A") -> will add "A" at i th position from head(i=0,1,2,..)
remove("A") ->  will remove "A" from LL
remove(i) -> will remove element from i th position
removeFirst() -> will remove (head)first element from LL.
removeLast() -> will remove (tail)last element from LL.
It will be helpful if you can provide this sort of detail.
```